# Put data from csv file automation testing

Tags: java, csv, automation, automated-tests, cucumber

Hi I want to put data from my CSV file used automation testing but I have error:Attempt to read from null array
My code:

```
public class TestData {
    String DataCSVPath = "src/androidTest/java/md/app/TestData/Data.csv";
    protected CSVReader csvReader;
    String csvCell[];

    public String readFile() throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(DataCSVPath));
        while ((csvCell = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            String Phone = csvCell[0];
            String IDNP = csvCell[1];
            String cardNumber = csvCell[2];

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My CSV file:
Phone,IDNP, card number

"064511418","59495955","9529525852"
And my automation step
onView(withId(R.id.et_phone_number)).perform(typeText(csvCell[0]));

In this line
onView(withId(R.id.et_phone_number)).perform(typeText(csvCell[0]));
I have error ttempt to read from null array

Hi I want to put data from my CSV file used automation testing but I have error:Attempt to read from      null array
My code:

```
public class TestData {
    String DataCSVPath = "src/androidTest/java/md/app/TestData/Data.csv";
    protected CSVReader csvReader;
    String csvCell[];

    public String readFile() throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(DataCSVPath));
        while ((csvCell = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            String Phone = csvCell[0];
            String IDNP = csvCell[1];
            String cardNumber = csvCell[2];

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My CSV file:
Phone,IDNP, card number
"064511418","59495955","9529525852"

And my automation step
onView(withId(R.id.et_phone_number)).perform(typeText(csvCell[0]));

In this line
onView(withId(R.id.et_phone_number)).perform(typeText(csvCell[0]));
I have error ttempt to read from null array

Comment: can you confirm that the answer I provided worked for you? If not, why not? Be specific so I could help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is your while loop. The loop won't stop until `CSVReader#readNext()` returns `null` in which case, the null value is set in the array variable. Later on, when you try to access this global variable, it is null.

Instead, if your `CSVReader` class has a `hasNext()` method, you should use that to control the loop iterations. When you have a next element, the code will go inside the loop. Then, it will be safe to set the array. If you do not have this method, you may want to create it. The code should look something like this:

```
while (csvReader.hasNext()) {
    csvCell = csvReader.readNext();
    // Why are the strings below necessary? You aren't using them.
    String Phone = csvCell[0];
    String IDNP = csvCell[1];
    String cardNumber = csvCell[2];
}
```

This approach guarantees the array will never be null so long it goes into the loop at least once.

If you cannot create a `hasNext()` method, you need to use a temporary array.

```
public String readFile() throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
    String[] temp;
    csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(DataCSVPath));
    while ((temp = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
        csvCell = temp;
        // Removed unnecessary strings
    }
    return null;
}
```